# Data visualization - surface with parametric colour

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a set of points in 3D in cartesian coordinates X,Y,Z. To every such point I associate a value which is stored in a vector C. I want to be able to colour the surface given by X,Y,Z with colors given by C. Alternatively, if possible, I would like to associate to each point a color from a finite number of given colors. In Matlab this is possible with surf(X,Y,Z,C), but X,Y must be in grid form (generated by meshgrid), not in general form, like in my case.

I managed to do this in the case of the sphere, but the procedure is not pretty, and it uses heavily the parametrization of the sphere. Here's an example of what I want to do (in the case of the sphere).
[image]

> Is there a way to do this type of surface coloring in Matlab? (if it helps, I can also provide a triangulation of the surfaces in addition to the points X,Y,Z)
>
> Is there another piece of software which can do similar things and can interface in some way with Matlab?

Comment: Yes, there is. You have triangulation? and you know which points you want ith which colour? `patch` is your friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Ander Biguri for suggesting patch. Here's what I've come up with, and it seems to work fine.

```
function patch_color_plot(struc)
% struc is a structure containing at least the following:
% points - the coordinate of the points in a 3xN matrix
% t      - the triangulation matrix
% x_0s   - the point values

fac  = struc.t;
vert = struc.points;
fvc  = struc.x_0s;

p =  patch('Faces',fac,'Vertices',vert,'FaceVertexCData',...
            fvc,'FaceColor','interp');

set(p,'EdgeColor','none')
axis equal
axis off`
```

Here's a sample result:

[image]

and another one with a torus:

[image]

here's another example:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I based this off of [Matlab's Representing Data as a Surface](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/visualize/representing-a-matrix-as-a-surface.html;jsessionid=7ee2f4220869b006816cafd86580). Does this work?

```
xlin = linspace(min(x),max(x),33);
ylin = linspace(min(y),max(y),33);
[X,Y] = meshgrid(xlin,ylin);
f = scatteredInterpolant(x,y,z);
Z = f(X,Y);

g = scatteredInterpolant(x,y,c);
C = g(X,Y);

surf(X, Y, Z, C)
```

Comment: In my case I have a closed surface, so interpolating everything as a function of x,y will not work for me.